# Advanced reference in Markov processes

Tags: markov-process

I am interested in a book which covers the more in depth stuff on continuous time Markov processes e.g. semi-groups, generators...

Preferably such book would also contain a list of analysis results which is needed. (in the appendix or as a stand alone section)

Any suggestions, people?

thanks a lot in advance.